# Modelling service errors - gRPC Vs Google API

Tags: go, google-api, protocol-buffers, grpc

Handling errors in a gRPC service commonly requires both a `status` message and error `codes`. Both have two definitions:

- Google APIs definition ([googleapis/go-genproto](https://github.com/googleapis/go-genproto)) - the generated Go packages for common protocol buffer types, and the generated gRPC code for Google's gRPC APIs
- gRPC definition ([grpc/grpc-go](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go)) - the Go implementation of gRPC

The Go packages for both definitions of `Status` and `Codes` are:

Google APIs

- Status: [google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status)
- Codes: [google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/code](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/code)

gRPC

- Status: [google.golang.org/grpc/status](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.42.0/status)
- Codes: [google.golang.org/grpc/codes](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.42.0/codes)

Since I'm a client of my own gRPC service and not a client of an existing Google gRPC API, I want to use the *gRPC* definitions of `Status` and `Code`.

However, the **gRPC** proto file for `Status` is actually copied from **Google APIs** definition. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/proto/grpc/status. The `go_package` of [status.proto](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/status/status.proto) is also unchanged, so both the Google API and gRPC definitions use the following Go package

```proto
option go_package = "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status;status";
```

The upshot is the only way to use `Status` when defining an API is by importing it with

```proto
import "google/rpc/status.proto";
```

...and importing the language bindings in Go with

```golang
import (
   "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status"
)
// Go server code...
```

But as stated earlier, this is wrong since I'm not a client of a Google API, but rather my own gRPC service. Therefore the language bindings should be imported with

```golang
import (
   "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)
// Go server code...
```

As expected if I switch to importing the **gRPC** language bindings and try and return a `Status` message to the API client, I get a compile error

```
cannot use &(status.Status literal)
(value of type *"google.golang.org/grpc/internal/status".Status) as 
*"google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status".Status value
```

This is caused by my `.proto` file using the Google API definition of `Status` while the server implementation (in Go) uses the gRPC definition.

The problem impacts error codes since Google APIs uses **signed** 32 bit integers (`int32`) whereas gRPC uses **unsigned** 32 bit integers (`uint32`).

Questions

- Is my assertion that I should be using the gRPC definition of `Status` and `Codes` correct?
- If my assertion is correct, how can I use the gRPC definition of `Status` when it's packaged for Google APIs?

Comment: am I understanding correctly — the main point of your question is how to use Status and Code *in protobuffer schemas* so that the generated code works with the `grpc-go` library?

Comment: If by "protobuffer schemas" you're referring to the `.proto` file defining the API/surface of my service, then yes, I think you've summarized my question better than me.

Comment: @blackgreen Sorry for not updating you. I actually created a bug in the [gRPC repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/27929) which has been assigned someone. I think this could be a bug and wanted to hear back from that before accepting this answer. I think your answer works, but it feels like a workaround?

Comment: Interesting, I’ve always assumed copy-pasting the googleapis proto file was a conscious choice, especially given the presence of the conversion code I mentioned below. But it may very well be a bug. Let’s see what they say

Comment: Good point about the conversion functions. I was a little put off using them when you said _"If you absolutely NEED to construct these [...]"_  - made me feel like they shouldn't be used. Also that gRPC status codes are unsigned whereas Google API status codes are signed worries me.

Comment: Yeah that sentence was maybe too strong. Of course if you are just constructing the Status value from scratch there’s no need to convert, you just init it with the googleapis type. But there are legit use cases for the conversion, e.g. if you want to push grpc errors (where Status is wrapped in response `error`) to some log processor that expects Status as a message field. Then you do `status.Convert(err).Proto()`

Answer (score 1):

We need to distinguish a few cases. Some of them are obvious, some are not.

#### Just returning `Status` from a gRPC handler

If your proto schema (`.proto` files) doesn't define messages that use `Status` or `Code` **directly**, then the gRPC handlers can satisfy the return type `error` simply with `"google.golang.org/grpc/status".Error()`, or `Newf().Err()`. And that's about it.

Example:

```
// implements SomeServiceServer unary RPC GetFoo
func (s *SomeService) GetFoo(ctx context.Context, req *grpc.FooRequest) (*grpc.FooResponse, error) {
    // status is "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
    return nil, status.Error(codes.Unimplemented, "coming soon")
```

#### Using `Status` in your `.proto` files

In this case, you are forced to use the `googleapis` implementation. As you already have seen, the `status.proto` Go package is defined as:

```
option go_package = "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status;status";
```

So let's say you have the following `.proto` file, where the imported `status.proto` is just a copy-paste of the [gRPC status.proto](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/status/status.proto) as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878404):

```
syntax = "proto3";

package test;

import "status.proto";

option go_package = ".;main";

message Foo {
  string a = 1;
  google.rpc.Status status = 2;
}
```

with directory structure as:

```
/protos
|_ status.proto
|_ test.proto
```

and you compile the above with:

```
cd protos && protoc -I=. --go_out=. test.proto
```

*breathe* ...then the generated Go code will have the following import

```
import (
    status "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status"
)
```

and you must satisfy that by `go get google.golang.org/genproto`.

So about your first question, you can **only** use `Status` from `googleapis` in proto files, because that's how `status.proto` declares its Go package.

#### Using generated `googleapis` `Status` in Go code

Since the imported Go package is from `googleapis` that is what you must use in your Go code in order to initialize such messages:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    googleapis "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status"
)

func main() {
    foo := &Foo{
        A: "foo",
        Status: &googleapis.Status{
            Code:    int32(code.Code_OK),
            Message: "all good",
        },
    }
    // fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

#### Yes but I *must* use `grpc-go` `Status` in my Go code

You can't. `protoc` generates code with the packages described above. If you absolutely *NEED* to construct these `Status` fields using `grpc-go`, you can use [`Status.Proto`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/internal/status#Status.Proto):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

func main() {
    foo := &Foo{
        A: "foo",
        Status: status.New(codes.OK, "all good").Proto(),
    }
    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

Just for the record, the opposite is also possible with [`status.FromProto`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.42.0/status#FromProto):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    googleapis_codes "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/code"
    googleapis "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

func main() {
    gapisStatus := &googleapis.Status{
        Code: int32(googleapis_codes.Code_OK),
        Message: "all good",
    }
    grpcStatus := status.FromProto(gapisStatus)
    fmt.Println(grpcStatus)
}
```

---

As a less well-behaved alternative, you can simply copy-paste the `status.proto` sources into your project and manually change the `go_package`:

```
option go_package = "google.golang.org/grpc/status;status";
```

This way `protoc` will generate the Go code with this import, and your own sources will be able to follow suit. Of course this means you now have your own fork of `status.proto`.